# Как сделать итерацию по нескольким singleton generic классам?

Tags: c#, generics

Есть основной класс

```
 class A { }
```

Есть шаблон для дженерик синглтонов:

```
class Singleton<T> : A where T : A {

    public string Name = typeof (T).ToString();

    private static T instance;        
    public static T Instance {
        get {
            return instance ?? (instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        }
    }

    public void TestMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("My name is " + Name);
    }
}
```

Есть пачка классов от него унаследованных:

```
class Test1 : Singleton<Test1> { }
class Test2 : Singleton<Test2> { }
class Test3 : Singleton<Test3> { }
class Test4 : Singleton<Test4> { }
```

Вопрос: как можно в основной программе иметь возможность всегда пробежаться по  им всем и обратиться к их методу/полю/свойству? чтобы не пришлось постоянно писать такие пачки:

```
Test1.Instance.TestMethod();
Test2.Instance.TestMethod();
Test3.Instance.TestMethod();
Test4.Instance.TestMethod();
```

Или в силу того, что это получаются разные типы - это невозможно?

Comment: Нужен общий интерфейс. Иначе нормальным способом никак.

Comment: @andreycha я кажется вырулил к этому только что сам) посмотрите upd. Получается тот способ самый правильный?

Comment: Да. В принципе `TestMethod()` можно и прямо в класс `А` добавить, но тут вам виднее должно быть. Общий интерфейс -- в смысле контракта.

Comment: @andreycha ну в данном случае класс `A` - это сторонний класс из dll, который не изменить...... Хм... то есть вопрос можно удалять похоже)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, перенеси свой UPD в ответ что ли :)

Comment: @Grundy завтра)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поддерживаю это решение. Плюс, хочу предложить как-нибудь переименовать заголовок. Например "Как обратиться к методу объявленному в generic классе если конкретный тип объекта неизвестен".

Comment: @Uranus длинное название)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, один из путей сделать интерфейс с общими методами

```
interface ICommon {
    void TestMethod();
    // ...
}
```

синглтон класс будет таким

```
class Singleton<T> : A, ICommon where T : A { ...
```

а в основной программе сложить в список и за счет общего интерфейса можно уже манипулировать всеми экземплярами:

```
List<ICommon> testList = new List<ICommon>();

testList.Add(Test1.Instance);
testList.Add(Test2.Instance);
testList.Add(Test3.Instance);
testList.Add(Test4.Instance);

foreach (var test in testList) {
    test.TestMethod();
}
```